# Excel Macro Macro / VBA Error 1004 - Copy Paste With Variable

Tags: vba, excel

Why does this work:

```
Sheets("Sheet1-Orig").Range(Sheets("Sheet1-Orig").Cells(20, 1), Sheets("Sheet1-Orig").Cells(LastRow1, 3)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("3-Orig_Merged").Range("A1")
```

But this throws up a 1004:

```
Sheets("Sheet2-Orig").Range(Sheets("Sheet1-Orig").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("Sheet1-Orig").Cells(LastRow2, 3)).Copy Sheets("3-Orig_Merged").Cells(LastRow1 - 18, 1)
```

Getting Application defined or object defined error. Driving. Me. Nuts...

Thanks!

Comment: The range and Cell object must be on the same sheet when using cells() inside Range().

Answer (score 1):

Even though there are more code lines below, I find it easier to use (and debug later):

```
With Sheets("Sheet1-Orig")
    .Range(.Cells(20, 1), .Cells(LastRow1, 3)).Copy
End With
Sheets("3-Orig_Merged").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: The biggest difference between the line that works and the line that doesn't work is that I am pasting to a defined cell (A1) in the line that works, but I am trying to paste to a variable (LastRow1 - 18) in the one that gives the error. The LastRow1 variable has the correct row number (65018) in it. It seems like I can copy using a variable in the range, but I can't paste to one?

Comment: @PaulDemay no the issue is that you are referring to two different sheets in  the range you are trying to copy.

Comment: OMG Scott - duh.